# Using ! bash history retrieval for commands starting with a digit?

Tags: bash, command-history, special-characters

Is it possible to use `!` to re-run a bash command line that starts with a digit?  I know that, [normally](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html#Event-Designators), `!<digit>` selects a command by position, and `!<text>` selects a command by text.  I am wondering if the `<text>` interpretation can be forced.

My use case is 7-zip, `/usr/bin/7z`.  I frequently do `7z e *.zip` in whichever directory I happen to be in.  I can't use `!7` to retrieve that command, in general.  My workaround is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and interactive history search.

I looked on Google, and I tried `! 7`, `!\7`, `!'7'`, and `!"7"`, without success.  Is there a way?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

```
!?string
```

will search the entire command line of history entries for `string`, rather than just matching on the start-of-line, so can be used to match commands beginning with a digit `n` without being interpreted as referring to the `n`th entry in history.

If additional history modifiers are to be added, the search string must also be terminated with a `?`, but in the event of a simple search-and-execute, the trailing `?` is optional.